Filtering windows from screen share?
I recently discovered the ScreenCaptureKit API which has the SCContentFilter interface to allow filtering sensitive windows from your screen capture.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/sccontentfilter
The problem is I don’t see any applications using this.
On Linux I can hide windows from the screen share at the compositor level. Meaning Zoom, Slack, Google Meet, etc. would never see the window to begin with.
An example using the niri compositor.
https://github.com/YaLTeR/niri/wiki/Configuration:-Window-Rules#block-out-from
Is there a way to globally filter specific applications from all screen shares? An app maybe?
